# Why Bootstrap DropDownMenu doesn't work when clicked?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a dropdown menu and include both signup and signin pages in it, but it doesnt work with me, the dropdown is not dropping down, even if I add a link in the ( `<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" ....`) it doesnt do anything... I appreciate your help in advance.

<--!  Code: -->

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Sign-in / Sign-up
                </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu drop" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="LoginPage.php">Sign-in</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="Signup.php">Sign-up</a>

                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: your code is working fine may be JS or CSS file missing https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/pw19cxdz/